# How to resolve a conflict between new \catcode for vertical bar and "tikz"

Tags: tikz-pgf

This is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\NewDocumentCommand\foo{v}{\texttt{#1}}
\catcode`\|\active\def|{\foo|}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
Hello, |world|!
\end{document}
```

It doesn't compile. What can I do?

BTW, I can't put `\usepackage{tikz}` on top of `\catcode`. This is just an experimental piece of code. My real case is much more complicated: I change the catcode of a vertical bar in my package, which could be used either before or after `tikz`.

BTW, somehow `ltxdoc` deals with this problem and this code works just fine:

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
Hello, |world|!
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never change catcodes before all packages have been loaded. `ltxdoc` uses `\AtBeginDocument` to make the bar character active as late as possible:

```
\documentclass{article}
\NewDocumentCommand\foo{v}{\texttt{#1}}
\begingroup
\catcode`\|\active
\newcommand*\usemybar{}% To get an error message, if it has already been defined.
\gdef\usemybar{\catcode`\|\active\def|{\foo|}}
\endgroup
\AtBeginDocument{\usemybar}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
Hello, |world|!
\end{document}
```

However, I would also suggest to define a command, to reset the catcode. So you (or other users) can easily switch back, if needed. To do so, you can add something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\NewDocumentCommand\foo{v}{\texttt{#1}}
\newcommand*{\resetbar}{}
\edef\resetbar{\noexpand\catcode`\|\the\catcode`|}
\begingroup
\catcode`\|\active
\newcommand*\usemybar{}% To get an error message, if it has already been defined.
\gdef\usemybar{\catcode`\|\active\def|{\foo|}}
\endgroup
\AtBeginDocument{\usemybar}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
Hello, |world|!
\resetbar
\begin{tabular}{|l|}% Without \resetbar this would be a problem!
  No Problem!
\end{tabular}
\usemybar
Hello, |world|!
\end{document}
```