# How to call a command with verbatim argument and normal argument both?

Tags: verbatim

This is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\NewDocumentCommand\foo{v}{\texttt{#1}}
\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`\|\active\def|{\foo|}}
\begin{document}
Hello, \foo{world}, |world|!
\end{document}
```

It doesn't compile:

```
! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text>
                \inaccessible
l.12 \begin{document}
```

How to fix this? I want to be able to call either `\foo{world}` or `|world|` and make them arrive to the same `\foo` command.

Comment: The catcode context of `\def|` is wrong. I've also shown how to make the catcode context correct [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/665206/277964).

Comment: your question does not seem clear and the code is unrelated to the question as `\foo{world}` and `|world|` both read the argument verbatim. The error is from `\AtBeginDocument{\catcode\`\|\active\def|{\foo|}}` as you need to make | active outside the macro, as always.

Comment: Maybe you just searching for package [`shortvrb`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/shortvrb).

Comment: I might have said this before, but if you haven't you can read TeXbook/TeX by Topic to understand exactly how the TeX parser/catcode changes work. Would take a while though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your setup you have already tokenized `|` as an 'other' character. You need to ensure that `\def|` happens when `|` is active. There are a few ways, for example

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\NewDocumentCommand\foo{v}{\texttt{#1}}
\catcode`\|\active
\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`\|\active\def|{\foo|}}
\catcode`\| 12 %
\begin{document}
Hello, \foo{world}, |world|!
\end{document}
```