# Why my verb-ish macro needs curled brackets in math mode?

Tags: math-mode

Thanks to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/665228/1449), I wrote this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\NewDocumentCommand\foo{v}{\texttt{#1}}
\catcode`\|\active
\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`\|\active\def|{\foo|}}
\catcode`\| 12 %
\begin{document}
$a_|b|$
\end{document}
```

I'm getting:

```
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again>
                   \tex_let:D
l.15 $a_|
         b|$.
```

However, `$a |b|$` works just fine. Also `$a_{|b|}$` also works. Is it possible to fix this and make it possible to use `$a_|b|$` (without the curled brackets around `|b|`)?

Comment: why support that syntax? subscripts should always be braced.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I can do `$a_\text{hello}$`, but can't do `$a_\foo{hello}$`

Comment: It is really unfortunate, undocumented and accidental that `\text` does not error  in that context

Comment: If your aim is to use `a_|b|` to get the subscript in `\mathtt`, you're using the wrong approach. Do you *really* need verbatim subscripts? With special characters such as `#{}`?

Comment: yes as egreg said I have been wondering why verbatim, none of the examples in your recent questions have needed that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that some commands, as an accidental sequence of undocumented expansions, do not give errors on horrible input constructions such as `x_\text{foo}` or `x^\frac12`  does not mean that such things need copying elsewhere. The documented latex syntax always braces subscripts.

That said, assuming you want to ignore this advice...

```
\documentclass{article}
\NewDocumentCommand\foox{v}{\texttt{#1}\egroup}
\catcode`\|\active
\def\foo{\bgroup\foox}
\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`\|\active\def|{\bgroup\foox|}}
\catcode`\| 12 %
\begin{document}
$a_|b|$
\end{document}
```